# Linq assign values from one table into another

Tags: linq, join

I am trying to lookup a value of an column from another table and later use the new looked up values in my where clause. For example, I have the following tables below

```
ID    Name
 1     Jan
 2     Feb
 3     March

Product    Customer  Start   End
  A          C        Feb    March
  A          B        Jan    March
  B          C        March  Jan
```

In the example above, I need to query for the list of records where Start ID is greater than the End ID. For example,  B-C-March-Jan is the record I am looking for.
Should I be using join? Also, if possible a query syntax would be very helpful.

My query:

```
 var vInvalidStartEnd = from p in vRecords
                        where (from t in vTimePeriods where t.Name == p["Start"] select t.TID).First().Cast<int>() > (from t in vTimePeriods where t.TName == p["End"] select t.ID).First().Cast<int>()
                        select new
                        {
                           Product = p["Product"],
                           Location = p["Location"],
                           Start = p["Start"],
                           End = p["End"]
                        };
```

Thanks

Comment: Are Start and End `DateTimes` or `Strings`? Is this C#, Linq-To-SQL or Linq-To-DataSet or Linq-To-Entities or ...? What have you tried?

Comment: Hi, the Start & End are string and this is Linq-To-Dataset. I will update my post with my current query. Thanks

Comment: @TimSchmelter I have updated the post with my query.

Comment: You're question is still not clear. What does _"Start ID is greater than the End ID"_ mean? Is this a typo since i thought that you want to compare the month-names and not the ID's? How are these tables related to each other? There is only an ID in the first table.

Comment: Tim, I am using ID as an example here. But the idea is to use the Name from Product to lookup an value from the Months table which will be of type int and then decide which is greater.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming ID defines what name is later than another.  Tim's issue in comments is probably because, first, it's unusual to use the name value as your link instead of the ID, and second, ID is a poor indication of which month is greater than another.  If I *had* to use month names the way you are, I would probably have an id, a name, and then an order value in the vTimePeriods table.

```
from p in vRecords
join start in vTimePeriods on p["Start"] equals start["Name"]
join end in vTimePeriods on p["End"] equals end["Name"]
where (int)end["ID"] < (int)start["ID"]
select new
{
    Product = p["Product"],
    Location = p["Location"],
    Start = p["Start"],
    End = p["End"]
};
```

I don't know the specifics of Linq to Dataset, but it would look something like that.

Comment: Yes Bert. I agree. I shouldn't have used ID and probably used a value like Priority or something